# PostgreSQL RETURNING fails with REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise, regexp-replace

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 and are inserting a lot of records into my database. I use the RETURNING clause for further use after an insert.

When I simply run:

```
... RETURNING my_car, brand, color, contact
```

everything works, but if I try to use REGEXP_REPLACE it fails:

```
... RETURNing my_car, brand, color, REGEXP_REPLACE(contact, '^(\+?|00)', '') AS contact
```

it fails with:

```
ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

If I simply run the query directly in PostgreSQL it does work and return a nice output.

Comment: Please make sure you don't accidentally turn off [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) (i.e. `select current_setting('standard_conforming_strings')`). -- It is enabled by default on and after 9.1. **If** it's `off`, than the syntax would be `'^(\\+?|00)'`. Also, there is a special syntax, which works regardless of this option: `E'^(\\+?|00)'`. But it is usually less surprising to leave it `on`.

Comment: It's on. Running the regexp_replace query manually also works, but adding it to RETURNING makes the insert fail.

Comment: can you please populate value of `contact` on which it fails?..

Comment: @VaoTsun it can be set per session

Comment: @VaoTsun it fails on all cases, ex. '+4422848566'. But running the query manually works. Again, it's only when in the RETURNING clause it fails.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen - please update original post with example of error, similar to the one in my "answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to reproduce and failed:

```
t=# create table s1(t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s1 values ('+4422848566') returning REGEXP_REPLACE(t, '^(\+?|00)', '');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 4422848566
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

So elaborated @pozs suggested reason:

```
set standard_conforming_strings to off;
```

leads to

> ```
> WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
> LINE 1: ...alues ('+4422848566') returning REGEXP_REPLACE(t, '^(\+?|00)...
>                                                              ^
> HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
> ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
> ```

**update**
As OP author says `standard_conforming_strings` is `on` as supposed from 9.1 by default working with `psql` and is `off` working with `pg-prommise`

**update from vitaly-t**

> The issue is simply with the JavaScript literal escaping, not with the
>   flag.

He elaborates further in his answer

Comment: I'm using pg-promise from nodejs to initiate the session and use the database.

Comment: Yes... Seems like it is a standard_conforming_strings issue, correctly as you described. Just don't know how to tell nodejs to have it on, as it usually is on when using psql.

Comment: Contact the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) or change the title to something like *Confusion with default value of standard_conforming_strings in pg-promise* and add tag `pg-promise` to the question (he looks here from time to time).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken - `pg-promise` just uses briancs `pg`, which btw does not change default value of `standard_conforming_strings`

Comment: @MichaelNielsen you can try adding `console.log("_send(code, more)", code, more);` to `connection.js` as described at  https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/314 - this should show you current `standard_conforming_strings` config value

Comment: @MichaelNielsen : Maybe you should add pg-promise to the tags for the question.

Comment: I'm the author `pg-promise`. The library doesn't do anything with the tags, neither does the underlying driver `node-postgres`. This is simply how the default database session is set up on the server.

Comment: Ok, I see. When I log in via pgsql "standard_conforming_strings" is on. But running queries via pg-promise requires \\ escape on strings.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen The variable is actually of no meaning in this context. See my answer.

Comment: @VaoTsun This is incorrect: `and is off working with pg-promise`. It is `true`, the same as with psql. The issue is simply with the JavaScript literal escaping, not with the flag. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The current value of environment variable `standard_conforming_strings` is inconsequential here. You can see it if you prefix your query with `SET standard_conforming_strings = true;`, which will change nothing.

Passing in a regEx string unescaped from the client is the same as using `E` prefix from the command line: `E'^(\+?|00)'`.

In JavaScript `\` is treated as a special symbol, and you simply always have to provide `\\` to indicate the symbol, which is what needed for your regular expressions.

Other than that, [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) will escape everything correctly, here's an example:

```
db.any("INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('hello') RETURNING REGEXP_REPLACE(name, $1, $2)", ['^(\\+?|00)', 'replaced'])
```

To understand how the command-line works, prefix the regex string with `E`:

```
db.any("INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('hello') RETURNING REGEXP_REPLACE(name, E$1, $2)", ['^(\\+?|00)', 'replaced'])
```

And you will get the same error: `invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`.